# Why can't a Self Organizing Map to recognize handwriting train to acceptable error rate when number of samples is greater than output neurons?

Tags: neural-networks

I have a simple Self organizing map that I have been working on.  It has an output neuron for all 26 letters, and when I provide it with 26 samples (one for each letter) it quickly is trained to an error rate below 1%.  It is fairly accurate, but when I want to add more samples, one for each output neuron, the lowest possible error rate shoots up to around 37%.  Even when I use a decaying learning rate it does this.  Even If I add one more sample so that I have 27 instead of 26 the training gets stuck on around 16% error rate.  I don't understand why as soon as I have more samples than the number of output neurons I cannot train it properly.  I am using the subjective learning method, yet the same happens when I switch over to the additive method.  I am still a beginner with neural networks so maybe I am not understanding something properly.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You have to keep in mind that SOM (Self organizing map) is an unsupervised learning algorithm,  most commonly used for clustering applications. In other words SOM isn't quite appropriate for solving pattern recognition problems (classification problems). You should probably try using an supervised learning algorithm like back propagation neural networks (feed-forward).

Moreoever, in the general case, you should have more samples for each classification category (each letter in your case). In order for your model to be trained and be able to generalize with an "acceptable" error in an unknown sample (sample that hasn't been used in the training set) you should certainly use more samples in the training set.

So, to cut a long story short:
1. If you want to use SOM, try solving a clustering problem.
2. If you want to solve the problem you are describing (pattern recognition), try to use a supervised learning algorithm
3. In either case the sample patterns must be more than one for each category.